# Is this the correct way to write asynchronous methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm currently trying to write async code and I have the feeling that my code is not too correct at all.

I have the following method:

```
public void Commit()
{
    _context.SaveChangesToDatabase();
}
```

Don't judge the code here as this are only samples. Also, don't say that if I'm using Entity Framework, that they come packaged with Async methods already. I just want to understand the async concept here.

Let's say that the method `SaveChangesToDatabase` does takes seconds to complete.
Now, I don't want to wait for it so I create an async method:

```
public async Task CommitAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Commit());
}
```

Does this mean that if I have a method:

```
public void Method()
{
    // Operation One:

    CommitAsync();

    // Operation Two.
}
```

Does this mean that my code on Operation two will be executed before `CommitAsync()` is even completed?

If not, please guide me in the right direction.

**Update**

Based on the remarks here that I'm ignoring my async method results, is this implementation better?

```
public Task<TaskResult> CommitAsync()
{
    var task = new Task<TaskResult>(() =>
    {
        try { Commit(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TaskResult
            {
                Result = TaskExceutionResult.Failed,
                Message = ex.Message
            };
        }

        return new TaskResult { Result = TaskExceutionResult.Succeeded };
    });

    task.Start();
    return task;
}
```

This does mean that I need to put the `async` modifier on the method that call this code so that I can await this which means continue with the current execution and return when this method has been completed.

Comment: I can understand the question but you could so easily test this yourself in virtually any environment, have you tried to test this yourself?

Comment: You'll generally find that `async` is "infectious" - once you apply it to a method, you'll generally then want to `await` in your calling methods, which then have to become `async` themselves, all the way up to the top.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to async so this might seem a trivial question for some persons but I just don't get it.

Comment: You can [play](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y8cL7E) with it yourself. And as @Damien_The_Unbeliever already mentioned, to have what you want you need `await` and to have `await` you need `Method()` to be `async` all the way up :)

Comment: I can recommend reading the blog posts by Stephen Taub over at MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Fire but don't forget

`CommitAsync()` returns a `Task`, but `Method` ignores the return value of `CommitAsync` completely -- so yes, the code will not wait but simply go on with what's after that. This is bad, because, if `Commit()` throws an exception, you will never see it. Ideally, every task should be waited on somewhere by someone, so you can at least see if it fails.

Let's say that you have no async alternative to `SaveChangesToDatabase`, but you'd like to use it in an async context anyway. You *can* use `Task.Run` to create a "fake-asynchronous" method, but this is not recommended (see below):

```
public Task CommitAsync() {
    return Task.Run(() => Commit());
}
```

And then, assuming `Method` is doing something interesting with async (which the below code does *not* do since it's the only asynchronous operation in there):

```
public async Task MethodAsync() {
    // Operation One:

    await CommitAsync();

    // Operation Two.
}
```

Assuming you do not want to wait, but you do want to do something if the task failed, you can use a separate method:

```
public void Method() {
    // Operation One:

    var _ = TryCommitAsync();

    // Operation Two.
}

private async Task TryCommitAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await CommitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Committing failed in the background: {0}", 
            ex.Message
        );
    }
}
```

### Getting back results

Let's suppose `.Commit()` does return something (like the number of records affected); a similar "fake-asynchronous" wrapper (again, not recommended - see below) would look like this:

```
public Task<int> CommitAsync() {
    return Task.Run(() => Commit());
}
```

If you want this result, you can await the task immediately:

```
public async Task MethodAsync() {
    // Operation One:

    int recordsAffected = await CommitAsync();

    // Operation Two.
}
```

Or, if you don't need it immediately, use `await` when you do:

```
public async Task MethodAsync() {
    // Operation One:

    Task<int> commit = CommitAsync();

    // Operation Two.

    // At this point I'd really like to know how many records were committed.
    int recordsAffected = await commit;
}
```

### Async: don't fake it

In general, you don't want to write wrappers like `CommitAsync()` because they [mislead callers into thinking code will be asynchronous when it isn't really](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), which brings few benefits other than not blocking (which is still useful in UI code, but not as good as true asynchronous code which doesn't need to use worker threads for everything). In other words, you should use `Task.Run` in the *invocation* of a method, not as the *implementation* of a method.

So don't, as a habit, write wrappers like `CommitAsync` for every synchronous method you have -- instead you want to make a true `CommitAsync` that uses the async support of the underlying libraries/frameworks (`SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()`, etcetera.)

If you have no choice and must use `Task.Run`, then the appropriate usage would look more like:

```
// This method is in the UI layer.
public async Task MethodAsync() {
    // Operation One:

    // Commit() is a method in the DA layer.
    await Task.Run(() => Commit());

    // Operation Two.
}
```

Comment: @Default Is there any violated rules?

Comment: @Default: partially because I could, partially because I don't feel I can address the issue adequately on my own, and I've seen lots of developers struggle with this. There's some potential here.

Comment: @stack oh no. Its just that he won't get any reputation points from upvotes. Personally I don't see the reason of community wiki unless it's been modified by multiple contributors or content that will probably change a lot.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What's the benefit of your code vs his initial code? From a quick test his initial code runs Async and would update the database but allow the rest of the code to execute as it did so. Yours requires the container method to also be Async, assuming I don't need the value of my Async operation why would I need to do this your way?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for that explanation it makes much more sense now. @ Complexity I ran this by simply executing the code in a small Console App and using WriteLines to log progress. And what Jeroen is essentially saying is that the code will run fine, but it is very bad practice to just run a method and not ever need to know what happened to it, i.e. your Database Update could fail and you would never know why.

Comment: Updated again -- as the site points out, extended discussions in comments are bad, so I won't keep commenting and I'm going to delete some that have become superfluous.

Comment: A very good idea, I've just updated my question aswell, you mind looking if that it's correct? If it's correct, it does mean that I'm beginnen to understand the async stuff thanks to your explanation. Thanks in advance. I would like this answer 100 times as the correct one :)

Comment: @Complexity: your code isn't handling the fault at all, it just passes it on to the caller. There's a much simpler way of doing that: just pass the entire task off to the caller. `Task` already has the properties you're after (`.IsCompleted`, `.IsFaulted`, `.Exception`), so you're using a superfluous wrapper.

Comment: @Complexity: well, no -- this does precisely the same thing as `return Task.Run(() => Commit())`. If you're catching the exception and turning it into a result, that still doesn't do anything if the caller doesn't await the task or its result. You cannot meaningfully handle the exception yourself, you have to leave it up to the caller (who would be quite confused if, instead of the regular `Task.Result` and `Task.Exception`, he had to deal with your `TaskResult` instead, just because).

Comment: Correct, but as told, this was a basic idea. Let's say then that I return a TaskResult that contains the number of failed rows and the caller would write this to a logger. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Complexity: yes, but then `Task<int>` will do, or, if your result is more complex, `Task<CommitResult>`. But `CommitResult` almost certainly should not contain a flag like "Succeeded", because you want the actual exception if something went wrong, and `Task.Exception` already provides this. A failed commit is probably an exceptional thing, not business as usual. If you are going this route, the very least you have to do is catch a specific exception type (like `DbException`).

Comment: I totally understand. One more very small question, and then this question is closed, when I do have a Task that returns an int, for the affected records, how can I also return the original task so I can see the exception and task result code? So I want to retrieve Task Result Code, exception message and an integer.

Comment: @Complexity: just return the task? If you return `Task<int>`, then the caller can either `await` this task, or they can use `Task.Result`. Both of these throw the original exception if the task failed. The whole point of `async`/`await` is that this is transparent and you don't have to shuttle things around yourself -- the only requirement is that you do, eventually, await the task somewhere, otherwise the exception goes into a black hole.

Answer (score 0):

Here

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B318#fbid=

is a good explanation on how to work with async, and why you should avoid "async over sync", which is what you are doing now with

```
public Task CommitAsync() {
    return Task.Run(() => Commit());
}
```

There are some scenarios where you can benefit from it, but if you are going to provide this as part of a library is NOT a good idea to make this.
If this code is ONLY and ONLY going to be used by your app, and you are sure what you are doing and dont have a wawy to call async methods inside your async method, just do it